# OpenVPN not default route

Tags: openvpn

Using Ubuntu 18.10 (or higher, if needed), I'd like to add a VPN connection but NOT make it the default route. Tons of people have the opposite problem, but I'd like tun0 to just be another interface I can choose to use.

How can I add an OpenVPN connection without making it a default, and without breaking other interfaces?

VPN config:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote vpn.com 1198
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
cipher aes-128-cbc
auth sha1
tls-client
remote-cert-tls server

user nobody
group nogroup
auth-user-pass .secret

compress lzo
verb 1
reneg-sec 0
<crl-verify>
-----BEGIN X509 CRL-----

-----END X509 CRL-----
</crl-verify>

<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>

disable-occ
```

Comment: Are you using `redirect-gateway` in your OpenVPN configuration? Could you post the configuration in the question (removing any sensitive parts of it)?

Comment: @Kusalananda, I'm not using redirect-gateway. It's a premade configuration from my VPN provider.

Answer (score 1):

The `client` directive is pulling your routes from your VPN provider.

Quoting from `man openvpn`,

> `--client` A helper directive designed to  simplify the configuration of OpenVPN's client mode. This directive is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> pull
> tls-client
> ```

Looking up `--pull` (which conveniently is the next entry in the man page), you get

> `--pull` This option must be used on a client which is connecting to a multi-client server. It indicates to OpenVPN that it should accept options pushed by the server [...]. In particular, `--pull` allows the server to push routes to the client [...]

So what you need to do is to ascertain what routes are being pulled by your client from the server, and add them yourself instead of accepting them blindly. For your configuration, that means you should replace `client` with `tls-client` and one or more `route` entries.

You can see the full set of routes with `netstat -rn` or `ip route` once you're connected, but remember that as these will include sufficient entries to ensure that everything is routed via the VPN, you won't want all of them.